# How to include a SSL Client Certificate when calling a restful web service in PERL

Tags: perl, rest, ssl, restful-url

I'm trying to call a restful web service off a Linux server. I was provide a .pem file to include in order to call it but i'm not sure where to add it in my PERL script. I keep receiving a "500 SSL Negotiation failed:" error

my .PEM file is called:

```
/u/data/aFolder/cert/theCert.pem
```

This is what I have for my PERL script

```
#!/opt/standard_perl/perl5881/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use Crypt::SSLeay;


#Validates that a url is passed via the arguements
my $global_url;
if (!defined($ARGV[0]))
{
    print "No URL passed";
    exit 400;
}else
{
    $global_url = $ARGV[0];
}

my $retry = 1;
# Retry logic, if service got a error code 500, it will
while ($retry <= 3)
{
    # Connects to service, if response was sucessfull then it prints he content
    # and exits the response code, else, retry 3 more times if the code was 500
    my $response = connectToService($global_url);
    if ($response->is_success)
        {
            print $response->content() . "\n";
            exit($response->code);
        }else
        {
            if ($response->code == 500 && $retry < 3)
            {
                $retry++;
                next;
            }
            print $response->status_line() ."\n";
            exit($response->code);
        }
}
######################################
# Passes the url and calls the service
######################################
sub connectToService
{
    my $url = shift;

    my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
    $request->header('Cache-Control' => 'no-cache');
    $request->header('accept' => 'application/json');
    return $agent->request($request);
}
```

My Result at the moment is:

```
username@theServer:/u/is/bin $ serviceCall.pl https://thewebServiceURL.com:3122/services/v1/quantity/foo/bar/info/11111
500 SSL negotiation failed:
username@theServer:/u/is/bin $
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way client certificates are used depends on the version of LWP and the underlying SSL library. With LWP version 6.0 (released 2011) [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#SSL_cert_file-SSL_cert-SSL_key_file-SSL_key) is used by default as the underlying library and there you give the certificates with `ssl_opts`:

```
$agent->ssl_opts(
    SSL_cert_file => 'cert.pem',
    SSL_key_file => 'key.pem'
);
```

With older versions of LWP [Crypt::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#Client-Certificate-Support) is used instead and then you need to specify the certificates with environment variables:

```
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = 'cert.pem';
$ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE}  = 'key.pem';
```

It looks like you are trying to enforce the use of Crypt::SSLeay but I actually recommend to use IO::Socket::SSL instead since it is the more modern SSL library, validates the certificates properly (contrary to Crypt::SSLeay), supports SNI etc.